# not positioned on a valid record

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Im New in Qt
I have problem in my app.
This is my code:

```
voidDialog::on_tableView_activated(constQModelIndex&index)
{
    QString valu=ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();
    QSqlQuery qryview;
    qryview.prepare("SELECT* FROM employ where nomper='"+valu+"' or prenomper='"+valu+"'");
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(qryview.value(0).toString());
    ui->lineEdit_3->setText(qryview.value(1).toString());
}
```

I want to recuperate my data in `QLineEdit`.

When I use SQLite, there is no problem.
But when I use MySQL no result shows in lineEdit.

> qsqlquery::value: not positioned on a valid record.

Comment: I think `SQLite` executes the query at once, because it supports only one statement in the `prepare()` .. So in case of MySQL, try to `exec()` the query after `prepare()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to retrieve the row without initializing it. The right way to do this is by using query.next(), below is the code example:

```
 QString valu=ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();
QSqlQuery qryview;
qryview.prepare("SELECT* FROM employ where nomper='"+valu+"' or prenomper='"+valu+"'");
qryview.exec();
while(qryview.next()) {
ui->lineEdit_2->setText(qryview.value(0).toString());
 ui->lineEdit_3->setText(qryview.value(1).toString());
}
```

This should work, if not try to print the lastQueryError and see if query is executed coreectly.